# How to run different scripts periodically but by running a command on a remote server

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh

So I am trying to make my code do the equivalent of this

```
ssh -i some-key.pem ec2-user@10.x.x.x 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

but what my code does is block until this command finishes. But it doesnt finish cause its on an infinite loop. So my program doesnt get any response from this command and so it gets stuck. I need to run many scripts periodically using the same command. Any idea how i can make some return to the code while still running the script on a remote machine in the background?

Comment: Two ideas: (1) You could run the ssh command in the background, and have _script.sh_ write its progress to some file, which you read on the calling side. (2) You can wrap the ssh call into, i.e., an [expect](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) program or something with similar functionality, have _script.sh_ write its progress to stdout, and interpret the stdout on the calling side.

Comment: @user1934428 but what happens if my script doesnt return anything?

Comment: So you want to check whether it is still running? You could do a ssh and run a `ps` to see whether your script is still alive. But: If you want to monitor the _progress_ of your string, you need to make your script in a way that it reports back the progress somehow. I mean, if you want to _see_ output, you have to _generate_ output, isn't it?

Comment: Try `ssh -f ...`